# Support both Azure AD and Custom Tokens in ASP.NET

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

Is it possible to support both Azure AD Tokens and Custom tokens for different areas of an application?

==Updated to add more detail==

I essentially want to use both the AddJwtBearer along with AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp method where My MVC Controller uses the Azure AD and my SignalR Hub uses the Jwt Bearer Token.

```
services
.AddJwtBearer(...) --> SignalR
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(...); --> MVC Controller
```

I have no problem authenticating against one or the other but I have not been able to authenticate both at the same time in a single ASP.NET Core site. It seems like the minute I add the Microsoft Identity it makes the whole site use Azure AD and sending any custom token to the site fails with Authentication Failed.

Is there a way to configure this?

Admin Controller --> Azure AD Auth

SignalR Hub --> Custom Jwt Token

Comment: Please share exact Authentication Failed error you are facing?

Comment: Unauthorized exception

Answer (score 0):

Standard project templates gives you "My organization", "Multiple organizations" or "Microsoft Account", to my knowledge (need to be careful in these .NET5 release times, things can change fast).

I suggest you look at AzureAD B2C [What is Azure Active Directory B2C?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview)
or IdentityServer4 [Sign-in with External Identity Providers](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html)

Comment: B2C would not work as we would need to sign in non-interactively. Do you know whether IdentityServer supports a "Service Sign-in" type of scenario?